# .NET enterprise application platform (same as JBoss to Java)

Tags: .net, jboss, middleware

As a .NET developer I'm asking whether JBoss alternatives exist to be "more suitable for .NET development" as an enterprise application platform.

Please do not make any suggestions, such as "make JBoss to expose WebServices"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java lacks a "hosting" solution - this is where (mainly) all the solutions like JBoss and WhebLogic are popping up from. In .NET you have so many different hosting solutions like: services, IIS, SQL, BizTalk ...

Now with the recent WCF features you can implement your own JBoss in 5 minutes - create an object with a Data and Messaging contracts, drop a couple of lines of config files to expose the interfaces via Web/Other services and define a threading model - you get your own JBoss. Java has no such story in their toolbox - this is why you need things like JBoss. [Of cause I'm oversimplifying things, but it's the truth in 80% of the time].

If you note that with the solutions like Apache CX Services - more and more people are moving away from JBoss. Now they can get an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not sure quite what you're looking for.  However, if you are looking for an Enterprise Application Platform for .Net you might take a look at our product, NetQuarry, at www.netquarry.com.

The NetQuarry Enterprise Application Platform uses IIS as the application server, and provides a feature-rich application support later on top of that including object relational mapping, rich AJAX UI, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for java app servers, there's WebSphere and WebLogic. But it'd probably be little different from jBoss from you prospective.

What are you looking for? What does jBoss do that you want the alternative to do? Are you looking for something in .NET? Is your .NET code a client that's going to interface with the server or are you writing a server in .NET?

Comment: What's about non-Java alternatives?

Comment: So you're looking for a .net app server, like jBoss is for java, but in .net. I think you need to rephrase you question to attract .net developers. Us java guys aren't likely to have a clue.